# Does a single endpoint and sequence numbers break REST's statelessness

Tags: database, rest, http

I'm working on a project that uses http to create a REST server. A client sends a request with just two fields: a sequence number, a client UUID, and a database ID specifying a database record to lookup. The client will later issue a second (or multiple) request to get the result of the request associated with the sequence number, and the server only does this if client is matches in both/all requests.  The entire project uses a single http endpoint (ie no subpaths), at http://localhost:80/.

Does this violate the statelessness property of rest, since the server needs to hold multiple responses indefinitely, and handle all replies via a single endpoint/path?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this violate the statelessness property of rest

In the context of REST, statelessness is usually shorthand for the [Client-Stateless-Server](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/net_arch_styles.htm#sec_3_4_3) architectural style described by Fielding in chapter 3 of his thesis

> The client-stateless-server style derives from client-server with the additional constraint that no session state is allowed on the server component. Each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is kept entirely on the client.

The web is the canonical reference application for the REST architectural style.  Here's was the HTTP specification has to say about [stateless](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.3).

> HTTP is defined as a stateless protocol, meaning that each request message can be understood in isolation.

If might help to consider the difference between HTTP and FTP.

For HTTP, an authenticated GET request is a *single* message, with an [Authorization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header.

[For FTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2), authentication commands are not part of the request; USER, PASS, RETR are all different messages sent from the client to the server as part of the same session.  The `RETR` command in isolation does not include the authentication context required to compute whether or not the access should be authorized.

I'm not convinced your design conforms to the *other* constraints in the REST architectural style, but *statelessness* isn't necessarily a problem here.